# GAS wont encode alternate MOV encoding

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, opcode, disassembly

I have a problem encoding a MOV instruction with alternate encoding with GAS.
I have the following instruction:

```
mov eax, 0x12345678
```

GAS gives the following encoding, both with .s suffix and without it.

```
b8 78 56 34 12          mov    eax,0x12345678
```

I'm expecting the following encoding:

```
c7 c0 78 56 34 12       mov    eax,0x12345678
```

Which disassembles to the same instruction obviously.
I'm trying to figure out how to make GAS assemble the following instruction with this alternate encoding.

Comment: Not sure there is a way to get it to encode that outside of coding it like `.byte 0xc7, 0xc0` followed by `.long 0x12345678`

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve. Why do you want GAS to output the alternate form? Are you writing an assembler or compiler?

Answer (score 1):

In past projects, I have occasionally encountered problems with an assembler/compiler wherein it would not generate the correct bytes for a given instruction.  The solution that was applied in those, I think would translate well to your situation.

Solution:  Hard code the instruction.  That is, if you want to force it to use 'c7 c0' ... declare a series of bytes in your code that match the instruction you want to generate.  Heck, you can even pretty it up with a macro.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although I agree with the hard coding solution(I suggested that as a comment), I just was going to make the observation that in this case the instruction being encoded by the assembler is correct, but the OP seems to want an equivalent but longer encoding.

Comment: Hard coding wouldn't really be a good solution for me at this point. I need the longer encoding or pretty much, I need all possible encoding for any instruction I give out. Think of this as a dictionary based on assembled instruction. I need to assemble all equivalents.

Comment: The hand coding using .byte and .long would encode the longer form of the instruction so that your resulting object/executable would have the specific instruction you want.

Comment: Your question didn't put any limitation on how to encode it. As the question is written this answer in fact valid. I would say you may have asked the wrong question or this borders on an XY problem

Comment: @DyCoder Thanks to prefix bytes, there's a huge number of possible ways to encode an instruction that stores 0x1245678 in EAX.

Comment: Also note that there are alternate encodings for other instructions too, where you don't even have the `.s` mechanism available.

Comment: So how can one actually use an assembler to assemble such instructions with these encoding??